# namespace dictionary confusion

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, namespaces

I'm trying to understand why one of these fails and the other works.

```
my_prd = { 'server': 'prd.my.company.com' }
my_lab = { 'server': 'prd.my.company.com' }
my_srv = {}

def test_fails(which):
    if which == 'prd':
        my_srv = my_prd
    else:
        my_srv = my_lab


def test_works(which):
    if which == 'prd':
        my_srv['server'] = my_prd['server']
    else:
        my_srv['server'] = my_lab['server']
```

Output:

```
fails: my_srv={}
works: my_srv={'server': 'prd.my.company.com'}
```

I'm going to move my reference logic outside of my function to deal with this, but I'd like to understand why `my_srv` is in scope enough that I can assign values to it but not in scope enough to be referenced or `copy()`ied?

Comment: In "fails" you just create a local variable that has nothing to do with the variable with the same name in the outer scope.

Comment: From [4.2.1. Binding of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names) - `The following constructs bind names:...assignment expressions` and later `If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block,...`

Comment: [4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) and [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) are worth read and re-reading - especially when you might be having scoping problems.

Answer (score 1):

In `test_fails()`, you assign `my_srv = my_prd` (or `my_srv = my_lab`). This means that `my_srv` is a variable referring to `my_prd`, like what we call a "pointer" in other languages (in Python, "everything is a pointer"). You can use `my_srv` for the rest of `test_fails()`, but once you leave the function that local variable is forgotten and `my_srv` refers once more to the empty dictionary.

Maybe this will help with what you were hoping to do:

```py
>>> my_prd = { 'server': 'prd.my.company.com' }
>>> my_lab = { 'server': 'prd.my.company.com' }
>>> my_srv = {}

>>> def test_fails(which):
...     if which == 'prd':
...         my_srv = my_prd
...     else:
...         my_srv = my_lab
...     my_srv["key"] = "item"
...

>>> print(my_prd)
{'server': 'prd.my.company.com'}

>>> test_fails("prd")
>>> print(my_prd)
{'server': 'prd.my.company.com', 'key': 'item'}
```

Comment: I used to do a lot of Perl and C programming so I get the reference/pointer part. But my_srv is obviously accessible (my_srv['server'] works) so I guess it's just an arbitrary Python thing to create a local version of my_srv when used with the brackets? I'm guessing there's no easy way to get around that?

Comment: @argel1200 because it isn't a pointer. Python *doesn't have pointers*, it's just all variables have "reference semantics". Assignment to a variable *creates a local variable*, but you can *access* variables in outer scopes

Comment: @argel1200 and by assignment, I mean something like `x = y`, on the other hand, `x[key] = value` is actually sugar for `x.__setitem__(key, value)`, i.e. a call to a mutator method, it doesn't affect any variable, it calls an method

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable inside a function, that variable is local by default, which means it ceases to exist as soon as you exit the function (and is not stored in the same place as global variables, so having a global and a local variable with the same name is not an issue), that's what you did by writing

```
my_srv = my_prd
```

when you exit test_fails() and access my_srv, python goes looking for my_srv in the global variables, which it finds untouched and equal to {}, the global my_srv and the local my_srv were never related, they just happened to have the same name but always resided in two distinct environments.

In test_works() however, you don't create any variable, you tell python to create an extra key/value pair in a dictionary that already exists, the my_srv global variable, therefore when you exit test_works() your work is still there.

Comment: Thanks! I wish the Python books out there would just spell out the variables are local by default. I have several and none of them clearly explain that.

Comment: @argel1200 I mean, it is pretty clearly stated in the [official tutorial on the section for defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions): "More precisely, all variable assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table; whereas variable references first look in the local symbol table, then in the local symbol tables of enclosing functions, then in the global symbol table, and finally in the table of built-in names...."

Comment: @argel1200 "... Thus, global variables and variables of enclosing functions cannot be directly assigned a value within a function (unless, for global variables, named in a global statement, or, for variables of enclosing functions, named in a nonlocal statement), although they may be referenced. "

Comment: Actual, books. such as Python Crash Course, Introducing Python, etc. Crash Course mentioned references very early which was a huge help, but Python's default to local variables wasn't called out. For veteran programmers new to Python, the books, tutorials, etc. are significantly less useful because there's so much new-to-programming material.  Like, all I really needed is somethin like:
1) Variables are references to the data
2) Variables are local by default, but global can be used to override that
3) The contents of dictionaries can be accessed from within functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Python creates local variables by default. There are some keywords like global and nonlocal (Python 3.x) that can alter how the namespace is handled. Edit:

In my case, this works:

```
def test_fails(which):
    global my_srv  #<<< Add this and it will work
    if which == 'prd':
        my_srv = my_prd
    else:
        my_srv = my_lab
```

A good reference I found is: [Global vs. Local Variables and Namespaces](https://python-course.eu/python-tutorial/global-local-variables-namespaces.php)

Comment: `global` has always existed, I believe `nonlocal` did not exist until Python 3, though.